# Query specific fields using JPA and Specifications

Tags: java, jpa, specifications

I'm trying to set specific fields on my query using JPA specifications using :

```
public static Specification<Contestation> fromContestation(QueryParams filters) {
    return ((root, query, cb) -> {
        root.get(Order_.orderDetails);
        root.fetch(Order.payment, JoinType.INNER);
        root.fetch(Order.feed, JoinType.INNER);

        return cb.isNotNull(root.get(Contestation_.contestationId));
    });
}
```

But it's not working, the query still retrieves all the fields. How can I do it?

Comment: A JPA `EntityGraph` allows you to choose what fields are fetched. Just putting a fetch join is only a HINT to include that particular field. And a `Specification` is nothing to do with the JPA API

Comment: Could you provide more details like Entity models, which fields are you trying to query, etc?

Comment: @BillyFrost a Specification is part of JPA Criteria.. i don't know what you mean.. but thank you about EntityGraph

Comment: Nope, JPA Criteria is part of the JPA API. `Specification` is part of SPRING, and not part of the JPA, and it USES "JPA Criteria".

Comment: @BillyFrost you're right. I'' try to use only criteria to build the query. I'm looking for a nice way to compose query and paginate..